Is there precedent or reason to not combine like terms in an equation?
So, I've been having a bit of fun and exploring the question of Odd Perfect Numbers. I figured I would try to keep things simple, and well. Things quickly became a complex mass of simplistic moves.
Here's my concern. In my exploration of this problem, I ended up creating a formula for integers with two sets of factors and 1.
$$A = BZ \rightarrow Z = \frac{A}{B} \rightarrow A = B * \frac{A}{B}$$
Set of Factors
$$A = \{ 1, B, \frac{A}{B}, C, \frac{A}{C} \} $$
Odd Perfect Number Equation
$$A = 1 + B + C + \frac{A}{C} + \frac{A}{B}$$
skipping several steps
Since all variables are presumed to be an Odd Integer,
Let the following definitions be true.
$A = 2a+1$ | $B = 2b+1$ | $C = 2c+1$
After you substitute these in for the Odd Integer Variables and start solving. I get to a conclusion of:
$$8abc +4bc -2a -1 = 8b^2c +8bc^2 +20bc +4b^2 +4c^2 +8b +8c +3$$
Here's my dilemma. If I combine like terms I get a simplified equation of:
$$8abc -2a = 8b^2c +8bc^2 +16bc +4b^2 +4c^2 +8b +8c +4$$
But by doing so, I have now converted both sides of the equation into Even Numbers.
So I am asking.
Is there precedent or sufficient reason for me to not move the constants when combining like terms?
Because the alternative is that no matter how many sets of factors I have. They all end up as Even Integers in the end

In the result do you expect any Odd Integers? But that's not going to happen, as both sides are odd at the beginning, and to be sure that they are, by definition they are of the form even-number-of-times-a-variable, not necessarily 2 times, plus an odd constant, not necessarily 1. Of course you can split this definition to many terms, on both sides, but to be sure it is odd, all variables are multiplied by an even number and then an odd constant is added (having like terms combined). Simplifying you remove the smaller constant from both sides and then the remaining constant becomes also even.

The body of your post digresses from the title, but it may be of interest to recall that solving quadratic equations by "completing the square" amounts to splitting (un-combining) the constant term.

So in the final steps of simplifying and combining. I should or should not be combining the constants? Like I said, every time do combine the constants it changes the final equation into an Even equal to an Even. But I'm starting from the point of view that all variables are Odd.
On its face, this implies a Proof by Contradiction that No Odd Perfect Numbers Exist.
But then I asked myself, if the combining of the Constants is what is causing this dilemma. Should I be combining them in the first place?
